# Proof that the orbits of the action of the Galois group on the roots correspond to the irreducible factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I've spent around 5 hours on this single proof but I still don't fully get it.

**Statement** (some terms might be unusual/imprecise because I'm translating, sorry about that).

"Let $L$ be a splitting field of a polynomial $f \in K[X]$. The orbits of the left action of $Gal(L|K)$ on $\{1,...,n \}$ correspond exactly to the monic irreducible factors of $f$. In particular, the action is faithful $\iff$ $f$ is irreducible."

I assume the set $\{1,...,n \}$ identifies the roots $\{a_1,...,a_n \} $ of f.

**Proof:**
Let $A \subset \{1,...n \}$ and set $f_A(X)=\prod_{ i \in A}(X-a_i)$.
$$ \forall \gamma \in Gal(L|K): \gamma (f_A(X))=\prod_{ i \in A}(X-a_{\gamma \cdot i})= \prod_{I \in \gamma A}(X-a_i)=f_{\gamma A}(X)$$
Hence
$$f_A(X) \in K[X] \iff \forall \gamma \in Gal(L|K): \gamma (f_A(X))=f_A(X) \iff  \forall \gamma \in Gal(L|K): \gamma A = A \iff A \,  is \; Gal(L|K) \, invariant$$
End of the proof.

I understand all of the above steps, however I do not understand the proof idea. We pick this polynomial $f_A$. Then we show that this polynomial is in $K[X]$ if and only if $A$ is $Gal(L|K)$ invariant, hence $A$ is an orbit. Is then $f_A$ automatically irreducible over $K$? Why? The biggest problem is that I don't see any correlation with irreducibility in this whole thing.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ need not be an orbit in order for $\gamma A = A$; it could be a union of orbits. So the final set of equivalences above shows that any union $A$ of orbits produces a polynomial $f_A\in K[X]$. It follows that if $A$ contains more than one orbit, then $f_A$ is reducible.

Conversely, suppose that $A$ consists of a single orbit, and write $f_A = gh\in K[X]$. Then $g = f_B$ for some $B\subset A$. But this forces $B=A$ since otherwise $\gamma B\ne B$.